# return value out of for-loop simple callback helper function

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to mach a value against an array inside a callback function. If it matches, return true out of that callback function & **break the for-loop as soon as possible instead of continuing the loop for all values**.

```
function arrayLoop(dataArray, callback){
  for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
      callback(dataArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Here is demo test

```
var arr = = [6,1,4,9,2];
var test = arrayLoop(arr, function(item){
    if (item==4) return true;
});
console.log(test); //it should show "true" in console.
```

Comment: Your `callback` returns a value, but the return value is ignored in your `for` loop. You’d need `break`. (`return callback(`…`);` will _not_ work as intended, as this misses the point of the loop). But why not just use [`find`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`every`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), or [`some`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: @Sphinx if `return callback(dataArray[i])` , it will break the loop on just first value & will not check next values.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I can't use them for compatibility issues. btw, can you show me how can I use. Me be then I can get idea to come up with my own solution.

Comment: @samar There are polyfills linked or shown in the documentation articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to break and return only when a truthy value is returned from the callback, this should be possible:

```js
function arrayLoop(dataArray, callback){
  for(var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
      console.log(`iteration ${i}`);
      let result = callback(dataArray[i]);
      if (result) {
        console.log('done!');
        return result;
      }
  }
}

function isFour(item){
    if (item==4) return true;
}


var arr = [6,1,4,9,2];
var test = arrayLoop(arr, isFour);

console.log(test); //it should show "true" in console.
```

However, I am not sure there is much value in this; as many of the comments stated, there are probably native ways for you to achieve what you are trying to do in a cleaner, more performant manner.  For instance, if all you are trying to do is evaluate if a certain item is in an array [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) would be a better approach:

```js
var arr = [6,1,4,9,2];
var test = arr.includes(4);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: You come up what I wanted. thank you. I'm testing further. then will accept your answer

Comment: `let result = callback(dataArray[i]);
      if (result) {
        console.log('done!');
        return result;
      }` , these are line that I need. thank you

Comment: I'm glad this helped you-- please remember to vote up and mark as correct.  However, I would recommend reviewing some of the other answers as well, and evaluating thoroughly whether or not what you are doing here is actually needed.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function arrayLoop(dataArray){
  for(var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    if(dataArray[i] == 4) {
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
//and run
var arr = [6,1,4,9,2];
var test = arrayLoop(arr);
console.log(test);
```

As Simon stated in comment "but why not just use find, every, or some".
You are trying to "reinvent the wheel".
Follows filter approach to your problem with the 'same' callback fn.

```js
var arr = = [6,1,4,9,2];
var test = !!arr.filter(function(item){
return item == 4;
}).length
```

the filter gets the array of values matched the return true;
// [4]
the length takes the integer
// 1
the !! in front convert the number to boolean
// true

Comment: That function is actually being used so many times in a big library. So I wanted to stick to it. btw, I can now get Idea from your answer & another user posted an answer just now. I can a little modify for my need. thank you